# learn c the hard way ex 26 trouble understanding function

Tags: c

Well, let's get this straight to the point. Currently I'm in battle with Zed's Shaw Learn C the hard way and I'm pretty stuck in his exercise 26. The thing is, that i can't understand what's going on in one var arg function - Shell_exec. Can someone explain to me, how this for-loops work and how they are related to var arg system?

```
*File shell.c*

include "shell.h"
include "dbg.h"
include <stdarg.h>

int Shell_exec(Shell template, ...)
      {
    apr_pool_t *p = NULL;
    int rc = -1;
    apr_status_t rv = APR_SUCCESS;
    va_list argp;
    const char *key = NULL;
    const char *arg = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    rv = apr_pool_create(&p, NULL);
    check(rv == APR_SUCCESS, "Failed to create pool.");

    va_start(argp, template);

    for(key = va_arg(argp, const char *);
        key != NULL;
        key = va_arg(argp, const char *))
    {
        arg = va_arg(argp, const char *);

        for(i = 0; template.args[i] != NULL; i++) {
            if(strcmp(template.args[i], key) == 0) {
                template.args[i] = arg;
                break; // found it
            }
        }
    }

    rc = Shell_run(p, &template);
    apr_pool_destroy(p);
    va_end(argp);
    return rc;

error:
    if(p) {
        apr_pool_destroy(p);
    }
    return rc;
}

int Shell_run(apr_pool_t *p, Shell *cmd)
{
    apr_procattr_t *attr;
    apr_status_t rv;
    apr_proc_t newproc;

    rv = apr_procattr_create(&attr, p);
    check(rv == APR_SUCCESS, "Failed to create proc attr.");

    rv = apr_procattr_io_set(attr, APR_NO_PIPE, APR_NO_PIPE,
            APR_NO_PIPE);
    check(rv == APR_SUCCESS, "Failed to set IO of command.");

    rv = apr_procattr_dir_set(attr, cmd->dir);
    check(rv == APR_SUCCESS, "Failed to set root to %s", cmd->dir);

    rv = apr_procattr_cmdtype_set(attr, APR_PROGRAM_PATH);
    check(rv == APR_SUCCESS, "Failed to set cmd type.");

    rv = apr_proc_create(&newproc, cmd->exe, cmd->args, NULL, attr, p);
    check(rv == APR_SUCCESS, "Failed to run command.");

    rv = apr_proc_wait(&newproc, &cmd->exit_code, &cmd->exit_why, APR_WAIT);
    check(rv == APR_CHILD_DONE, "Failed to wait.");

    check(cmd->exit_code == 0, "%s exited badly.", cmd->exe);
    check(cmd->exit_why == APR_PROC_EXIT, "%s was killed or crashed", cmd->exe);

    return 0;

error:
    return -1;
}

Shell CLEANUP_SH = {
    .exe = "rm",
    .dir = "/tmp",
    .args = {"rm", "-rf", "/tmp/pkg-build", "/tmp/pkg-src.tar.gz",
        "/tmp/pkg-src.tar.bz2", "/tmp/DEPENDS", NULL}
};

Shell GIT_SH = {
    .dir = "/tmp",
    .exe = "git",
    .args = {"git", "clone", "URL", "pkg-build", NULL}
};

Shell TAR_SH = {
    .dir = "/tmp/pkg-build",
    .exe = "tar",
    .args = {"tar", "-xzf", "FILE", "--strip-components", "1", NULL}
};

Shell CURL_SH = {
    .dir = "/tmp",
    .exe = "curl",
    .args = {"curl", "-L", "-o", "TARGET", "URL", NULL}
};

Shell CONFIGURE_SH = {
    .exe = "./configure",
    .dir = "/tmp/pkg-build",
    .args = {"configure", "OPTS", NULL},
};

Shell MAKE_SH = {
    .exe = "make",
    .dir = "/tmp/pkg-build",
    .args = {"make", "OPTS", NULL}
};

Shell INSTALL_SH = {
    .exe = "sudo",
    .dir = "/tmp/pkg-build",
    .args = {"sudo", "make", "TARGET", NULL}
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you call Shell_exec, you'd call it like this:

```
Shell_exec(foo, bar, baz);
```

Then you do

```
va_start(argp, template);
```

Which tells the computer "Okay, starting after FOO (or 'template' inside the function) put everything else in the argp variable and end the argp variable with NULL"

So, inside argp it looks something like this:

```
argp == [&bar, &baz, NULL]
```

When it hits the for loop, what va_arg does is that it removes the first entry from argp and then goes to the location of bar. However, it doesn't actually know what bar is, so you have to tell the va_arg what type of variable is contained at the address, so argp is now

```
argp == [&baz, NULL]
key == bar
```

HOWEVER, you notice that there's another va_arg in the loop itself! That consumes another variable from argp!

```
argp == [NULL]
key == bar
arg == baz
```

The next iteration of the loop ends it, since

```
argp == []
key == NULL
```

Notice that since the for loop consumes two arguments from Shell_exec, you must always have an ODD number of arguments when calling Shell_exec (One template argument, then always an even number).

The actual idea behind it is that when you call Shell_exec, you call it like this:

```
Shell_exec(TAR_SH, "TARGET", "./install/file/location");
```

So you look at your TAR_SH structure, notice that there is the default argument "TARGET" and then replace it with "./install/file/location". Repeat for however many arguments you want to replace then send the resulting modified TAR_SH off to some other function.

Hope this helps.